# How to upload an image in React JS?

Tags: reactjs

```js
<div className="mb-1">
     Image <span className="font-css top">*</span>
     <div className="">
         <input type="file" id="file-input" name="ImageStyle"/>
     </div>
</div>
```

This is the snippet i provided that i was using to pick the file from the device in react js,
Using this i can select the file and that filename is also shown as well 
What i want is now to store this file on S3 or anywhere and get its URL from there and POST it to my server using fetch api call.

Answer (score 75):

```
import React, { useState } from "react";

const UploadAndDisplayImage = () => {

  const [selectedImage, setSelectedImage] = useState(null);

  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Upload and Display Image usign React Hook's</h1>

      {selectedImage && (
        <div>
          <img
            alt="not found"
            width={"250px"}
            src={URL.createObjectURL(selectedImage)}
          />
          <br />
          <button onClick={() => setSelectedImage(null)}>Remove</button>
        </div>
      )}

      <br />
      <br />
      
      <input
        type="file"
        name="myImage"
        onChange={(event) => {
          console.log(event.target.files[0]);
          setSelectedImage(event.target.files[0]);
        }}
      />
    </div>
  );
};

export default UploadAndDisplayImage;
```

Comment: This worked beautifully in my nextjs site, and I could insert it seamlessly without needing to worry about classes or render(), thank you so much and may all your programs compile on their first run

Comment: good job, but after removing the image, it stops working on my end

Comment: For making work after removing the image, you need to clear the file input as well.

Answer (score 35):

Upload the image from your file and display it on your page in react,
you can also get the image object in the state when we select the image
to display on the webpage you have to convert the image object to object using   URL.createObjectURL(fileObject)

```
import React, { Component } from "react";

class DisplayImage extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      image: null
    };

   // if we are using arrow function binding is not required
   //  this.onImageChange = this.onImageChange.bind(this);
  }

  onImageChange = event => {
    if (event.target.files && event.target.files[0]) {
      let img = event.target.files[0];
      this.setState({
        image: URL.createObjectURL(img)
      });
    }
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <div>
          <div>
            <img src={this.state.image} />
            <h1>Select Image</h1>
            <input type="file" name="myImage" onChange={this.onImageChange} />
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
export default DisplayImage;
```

Comment: you don't need `this.onImageChange = this.onImageChange.bind(this);
` if you have a arrow function

Comment: check the updated code using react hook's check the link 
 ==> https://stackoverflow.com/a/68979570/8621764

Answer (score 3):

If you want to upload image and post it to an API. Then you install `react-image-uploader`. It saves the image to your local port and also in your database by raising a POST request.

Answer (score 2):

This code let you upload image to the server,the backend code is written in `nestjs`,and display the image which will be uploaded.I have used the `formdata`.

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
function Product() {

    const { REACT_APP_REST } = process.env;

    const [file, setFile] = useState([]);

    const handleFile = event => {
        setFile(
            URL.createObjectURL(event.target.files[0])
        );
        const formData = new FormData();
        formData.append("fileupload", event.target.files[0]);

        fetch(REACT_APP_REST + "/product/upload", {
            method: 'POST',

            body: formData,
            dataType: "jsonp"
        })
    };
    return (
        <>
            <Container fluid>
                <Col md="4">
                    <Card className="card-user">
                        <img src={file} />
                        <Card.Body>
                            <Form.Group>
                                <label>IMAGE</label>
                                <Form.Control
                                    type="file"
                                    required="required"
                                    onChange={handleFile}
                                ></Form.Control>
                            </Form.Group>
                        </Card.Body>
                        <hr></hr>

                    </Card>
                </Col>
            </Container>
        </>
    );
}

export default Product;
```

Answer (score 0):

using [react-uploady](https://github.com/rpldy/react-uploady) you can do this very easily:

```js
import React from "react";
import Uploady from "@rpldy/uploady";
import UploadButton from "@rpldy/upload-button";
import UploadPreview from "@rpldy/upload-preview";

const filterBySize = (file) => {
  //filter out images larger than 5MB
  return file.size <= 5242880;
};

const App = () => (
  <Uploady
    destination={{ url: "my-server.com/upload" }}
    fileFilter={filterBySize}
    accept="image/*"
  >
    <UploadButton />
    <UploadPreview />   
  </Uploady>
);
```

Answer (score 0):

**Failed to execute 'createObjectURL' on 'URL': Overload resolution failed.**

For some reason I coudn't use URL.createObjectURL(image) as

```
  const [image, setImage] = useState(null);
  const [imgURL, setImgURL] = useState();

<img src={URL.createObjectURL(image)}/>
```

So I save the Url in the state for instant display on the button click method. This worked!

```
setImgURL(URL.createObjectURL(image));
```

Unfortunately, I was still getting the same error when I use useEffect.

```
  useEffect(() => {
    setImgURL(URL.createObjectURL(image));
  }, [image]);
```