# Passing Uploaded Image File from React Frontend to Next.js/Firestore Backend

Tags: node.js, reactjs, firebase, next.js

I would like to provide a form for users to upload image files to Firestore. From the form I wrote, I can obtain the user's chosen files as javascript [File](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/File) object.

I wrote the following function to call from my Next.js API to upload the image:

```
import {admin, app} from "firebase-admin";

const uploadImage = async (file) => {
  const storageRef = app.storage().ref();
  const fileRef = storageRef.child(file.name);

  
  await fileRef.put(file);

  return await fileRef.getDownloadUrl;
};

export default { uploadImage };
```

However, I have no idea how to pass the file from my React frontend to the function I wrote. Any help or explanation?

Comment: The most common example would be a fileupload input in an html form:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43692479/how-to-upload-an-image-in-react-js

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to upload an image in React JS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43692479/how-to-upload-an-image-in-react-js)